# sudo does not preserve TMPDIR

Tags: environment-variables, sudo, tmp

The sudo manpage tells me, that I can preserve the environment by passing the `-E` option, which does not work in the case of `$TMPDIR`:

```
> env | grep TMPDIR
TMPDIR=/localdata/tmp
> sudo env | grep TMPDIR
[no output]
> sudo -E env | grep TMPDIR
[no output]
```

This option is not blacklisted, that is `sudo sudo -V` doesn't list it as "Environment variables to remove". Following the approach proposed in an answer the the question "[How to specify root's environment variables](https://serverfault.com/questions/62178/how-to-specify-roots-environment-variable)", I tried to whitelist it, that is my `/etc/sudoers` reads:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        env_keep = "TMPDIR"
```

This doesn't work neither, it actually doesn't even make `TMPDIR` appear in the whitelist (that is, what ``sudo sudo -V` prints as "Environment variables to preserve".

(I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.)

Comment: Is $TMPDIR marked for export? `export TMPDIR`

Comment: I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 12.10, and yes, $TMPDIR is marked for export.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like glibc will remove certain environment variables when running setuid programs (`sudo` is, of course, setuid).  TMPDIR is one of these environment variables, although it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.  This is a security feature to prevent setuid programs from having their environments altered to allow for malicious reading/writing of file data.

- Reference: [ld.so clears TMPDIR for setuid programs](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-glibc/2003-08/msg00076.html)
- Reference: [TMPDIR ignored when setuid for dumpcap](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/2516/tmpdir-ignored-when-setuid-for-dumpcap)

If you want `TMPDIR` in your sudo environment, you can pass it explicitly:

```
sudo TMPDIR=$TMPDIR env
```

Comment: Thanks - Your second reference leads to a Bugzilla entry, closed as notabug, claiming that this behaviour is documented in [ld.so(8)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), which I cannot confirm.

Comment: @hrunting, thanks a ton for this tip. I've just been struggling to get a build script for an embedded device to run because it wants 8 GB of scratch space in `/tmp`, but my VM's drive only has 2 GB free. I tried specifying `TMPDIR` _before_ `sudo`, but this _does not work_. Putting it after worked like a charm. Thanks!